# Using Karate inside a SBT project

Tags: scala, testing, sbt, karate

I am using Karate to write integration tests inside a Scala/SBT project. Moreover, the integration tests written with Karate are also used as Performance tests as written in the [documentation](https://github.com/intuit/karate)

> Karate is the only open-source tool that combines web-API testing and test-doubles into a single, unified test automation framework. And you can re-use API Functional Tests as Performance Tests !

Later in the documentation, it's noted than we can use [Cucumber Options](https://github.com/intuit/karate#cucumber-options) to launch one or more test as `mvn test -Dtest=CatsRunner`. As all the example use maven, and I use SBT.

So I tried to launch one test with this command `sbt test -Dtest=CatsRunner` but with no success.

Have you any ideas to launch one Karate test with SBT ?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The latest 0.8.0 version introduced a Java API that does not need the Cucumber annotation. There is an example here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/DemoTestSelected.java

```
    List<String> tags = Arrays.asList("~@ignore");
    List<String> features = Arrays.asList("classpath:demo/cats");
    String karateOutputPath = "target/surefire-reports";
    KarateStats stats = CucumberRunner.parallel(tags, features, 5, karateOutputPath);
```

This is designed for parallel execution. But it should be easy for you to pass a single feature in the `features` array and use 1 thread.

I can add the capability to run a single feature similar to the JUnit `@RunWith(Karate.class)` annotation in the next version, via a Java API instead of an annotation, feel free to submit a feature request. If you search the doc you will find a way to run a single feature via a Java API - but it does not emit a report.